# How to use ColumnTransformer and FunctionTransformer to apply the same function to many columns, but separately?

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, feature-engineering, pipelines

I want to apply pd.cut as a transformer in a pipeline, like this:

```
numerical_preprocessing = Pipeline([
            ('cut_into_bins', FunctionTransformer(pd.cut, kw_args={'bins': [10, 100, 1000]})
             )]
```

However, I get an error: `ValueError("Input array must be 1 dimensional")` 
I could just write the same function over and over again with each column separately, but that looks like a terrible coding practice. Any thoughs on this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by creating a wrapper around pd.cut, which then applies pd.cut using the apply method of DataFrame:

```
if isinstance(x, pd.Series):
    return pd.cut(x, bins_final, labels=labels, **kwargs)
elif isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame):
    return x.apply(pd.cut, args=(bins_final,), axis=0, labels=labels, **kwargs)
```